# Add EFI partition to bios menu after NVRAM reset

Tags: multi-boot, bootloader, efi

Everything was fine at the start, my SSD has 2 EFI partitions and I usually switch between OS using the f12 key keeping Linux as default. But, after I cleared NVRAM, the Windows boot manager is there but Linux EFI got disappeared. How to add it back to the boot menu?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would guess that the Windows boot manager also vanished, but either the UEFI firmware included code to automatically add it back, or alternatively Windows first booted using the fallback UEFI bootloader path (`\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi`) and added the proper NVRAM boot variable back as a fully automated "self-healing" operation.

This would be easiest to fix using a Linux live boot media that is bootable *UEFI native mode*. That would allow you to use the `efibootmgr` command.

After booting Linux from a live media, you should first mount the EFI System Partition (ESP for short) of the Linux installation to the customary location of your Linux distribution (usually `/boot/efi`, but some distributions may use just `/boot`). Then, you should find the UEFI bootloader directory as `/boot/efi/EFI/<name of your Linux distribution>/` and files like `shimx64.efi` and/or `bootx64.efi` in that directory. There may well be other files too.

If the bootloader directory includes `shimx64.efi`, use it as the `<bootloader file>` in the next step; if not, use `grubx64.efi` if it exists.

Assuming that the Linux ESP is located on disk `/dev/sda`, the `efibootmgr` command to recreate the boot entry to the firmware menu will be:

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -l \\EFI\\<name of your distribution>\\<bootloader file> -L "<the name you want to see in the firmware menu>"
```

As you have multiple ESPs on the same disk, you might have to specify the correct ESP device name instead of just specifying the disk (i.e. something like `-d /dev/sda5` instead of just `-d /dev/sda`).

After that, use `efibootmgr -v` to view the boot settings. You may have to either use `efibootmgr --bootorder` to adjust the boot order to make Linux be the default, or visit the BIOS settings to do the same (some UEFI firmwares may reject boot order changes done using `efibootmgr --bootorder` - this is probably a firmware bug).

If you want to make Linux be the "survivor OS" whenever NVRAM is reset, you could reinstall UEFI GRUB using the `--force-extra-removable` option once you have your OS successfully booted, with a command like this:

```
sudo grub-install --force-extra-removable --uefi-secure-boot /dev/sda
```

(If you have Secure Boot disabled on your system, and plan to keep it disabled, you can omit the `--uefi-secure-boot` option if you wish.)